# theme not working in mui and nextjs 13 when i refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, next.js13

i use nextjs 13 and mui as ui library. i define my main layout file like this:

```
"use client";

import "./globals.css";

import shabnam from "@/utils/shabnam";
import ReactQueryProvider from "@/providers/ReactQueryProvider";
import RTLCacheProvider from "@/providers/RTLCacheProvider";
import CustomThemeProvider from "@/providers/CustomThemeProvider";
import JalaliLocalizationProvider from "@/providers/JalaliLocalizationProvider";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="fa" dir="rtl" className={shabnam.className}>
      <CustomThemeProvider>
        <ReactQueryProvider>
          <RTLCacheProvider>
            <JalaliLocalizationProvider>
              <body>{children}</body>
            </JalaliLocalizationProvider>
          </RTLCacheProvider>
        </ReactQueryProvider>
      </CustomThemeProvider>
    </html>
  );
}
```

and this is my Theme provider:

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import ThemeProvider from "@mui/material/styles/ThemeProvider";
import ThemeOptions from "@/theme";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

function CustomThemeProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(ThemeOptions), []);
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
}

export default CustomThemeProvider;
```

also this is my theme options:

```
import { grey } from "@mui/material/colors";
import { PaletteOptions, ThemeOptions } from "@mui/material/styles";

const paletteColors: PaletteOptions = {
  mode: "light",
  primary: {
    main: "#1F71BD",
    dark: "#030B13",
  },
  secondary: {
    main: "#FCA311",
  },
  success: {
    main: "#36B368",
  },
  warning: {
    main: "#FCA311",
  },
  error: {
    main: "#FF7473",
  },
};

const ThemeOptions: ThemeOptions = {
  direction: "rtl",
  palette: paletteColors,
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "var(--font-shabnam)",
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeightLight: 300,
    fontWeightRegular: 400,
    fontWeightMedium: 500,
  },
  components: {
    MuiSwitch: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          width: 46,
          height: 26,
          padding: 0,
        },
        thumb: {
          boxSizing: "border-box",
          width: 22,
          height: 22,
          color: "#fff",
        },
        track: {
          borderRadius: 13,
          backgroundColor: "#E9E9EA",
          opacity: 1,
          transition: "background-color 300ms",
          ".Mui-checked.Mui-checked + &": {
            opacity: 1,
          },
        },
        switchBase: {
          padding: 0,
          margin: "2px",
          transitionDuration: "300ms",
        },
      },
    },
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          borderRadius: "15px",
          boxShadow: "0px 0px 15px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1)",
          padding: "15px",
        },
      },
    },
    MuiLink: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          textDecoration: "none",
        },
      },
    },
    MuiPagination: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ theme }) => ({
          direction: "ltr",
          marginTop: "10px",
          "& .Mui-selected": {
            color: "white !important",
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main + " !important",
          },
        }),
        ul: {
          justifyContent: "center",
          "& .MuiPaginationItem-root": {
            borderRadius: "12px",
            background: grey[200],
            border: "0px",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& fieldset": {
            borderRadius: "15px",
            "& legend": {
              display: "none",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    MuiInputLabel: {
      defaultProps: {
        shrink: true,
      },
    },
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: (props) => ({
          marginTop: props.ownerState.label ? "40px" : "0px",
          "& .MuiFormLabel-root": {
            top: "-20px",
            fontSize: "22px",
          },
          "& .MuiFormLabel-shrink": {
            shrink: true,
          },
          "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            top: "2px",
          },
          shrink: true,
        }),
      },
    },
  },
};

export default ThemeOptions;
```

when i first start application it looks good and every thing is good.
here is a image of it:
[image: currect image]

but when i refresh the page the styles are get messy and it became this:
[image: wrong image]

as you can see styles are not set here currectly.
also if i change the route navigation my next router and get back here by also next router the style shows currectly. but not in refreshing the browser. also if i stop dev server and run npm run dev it gets ok till i refresh the page or add some change in code.

how can i fix this? Do you have any suggestions?
thanks!

i try to change use memo to use state in themeprovider but it didn't work!

Comment: Did you configure the `@emotion` package into your project? Or did you try adding the `CssBaseline` component after `ThemeProvider`?

Comment: yes i add emotion and here is my emotion code: ```"use client";

import rtlPlugin from "stylis-plugin-rtl";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";
import { prefixer } from "stylis";

// Create rtl cache
const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: "muirtl",
  stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin],
});

function RTLCacheProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>{children}</CacheProvider>;
}

export default RTLCacheProvider;
```

Comment: i also try to change ThemeProvider possition